# Network issue with Ubuntu 14.04.3 in Hyper V environment / not running stable

Tags: networking, crash, hyper-v

I think I have problems with my network connection on my 14.04.3 x64 servers.

What happened up to now:
A few month ago, I installed Ubuntu server 14.04.1 on a physical PC. I installed Samba, LAMP (for subversion access), Firebird-SQL-Server and that's it. Everything works fine. We planed to change the physical PC to a virtual machine and I installed everything on a Hyper-VM system (running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 host). Everything here works fine, too.

I updated both servers everytime with "apt-get dist-upgrade" and so I have Ubuntu 14.04.3 on them now. But since I updated to 14.04.3, I got problems with my network connections.

The issue is the same on both machines (physical an VM).
When I try to access the Samba shares from my Windows notebook (or accessing subversion repositories), it works several minutes, and then the system crashes.

On the physical PC, I can't access via PuTTY (ssh) and I can't login at the PC itselfs. When I press the Numlock key on the keyboard, the LED doesn't changed the state.

On the VM, I can't access via PuTTY, but when I use the console, I still can controll the VM. I found an article (https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/Dn531029.aspx) and I installed the packages they mentioned. But I still have the problem.
While I was restoring archive files (created on the physical PC) on the VM (I had access via PuTTY), the system crashes, too (but only the network device). Accessing via console still works.

To keep my daily business alive, I reinstalled my physical PC with 14.04.2, and I don't have any problems any more (up to now).

Is there anything I can do to get the 14.04.3 version running (primary on the VM)? Otherwise I think I have to reinstall 14.04.2 on the VM, too. Or do you now any command / service I have to call / restart to get the network running again?

Regards,

Rainer

Answer (score 0):

After I had reinstalled 14.04.2 on the pysical PC and just made apt-get upgrade (not dist-upgrade), everything works fine (the login screen shows 14.04.3, but the kernel is still 3.16.0.30).

I made the same steps on the VM and there it works fine, too.

So I think the problem is part of the kernel (3.19) which is installed from the 14.04.3 installation ISO file.